# Real Meaning of Polyglot Store?

Tags: oracle, cassandra, hbase, nosql

What is the real meaning of `Polyglot Store` from `NoSQL` perspective

1. Does it means any type of object
2. Does it mean any language capable of talking to your `NoSQL` product

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, Polyglot from NoSQL perspective has a much broader sense than just objects and languages. I feel that it signifies the fact that based on the way data is used by a user or an application multiple data stores can be used. The scope here is not limited to just types of languages which can talk to the store or different types of objects that can be handled. We are rather talking about having **n different stores for n different needs**.

What does it mean? As enterprise application are becoming more and more complex, it doesn't make much sense trying to fit everything in one model. We could instead harness multiple data stores based on our needs and take advantage of strengths of each of these stores individually. We don't have to force or fit our data/application into the store(as we need to do in case of traditional systems). We rather have to choose the appropriate store from the lot of all available stores which fits into our application or the data.

For instance, if you are the owner of a social networking portal you could use :

- **HBase for inbox messages**
- **Cassandra for activity log**
- **Neo4j for the social graph**

etc etc. You don't have to bang your hand to fit all these different types of data into a single store.

I don't know if this is what you were expecting. But this is how I imagine **Polyglot in terms of NoSQL**.